# Get current method and class without exception and without using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am wanting to log out some INFO logging in a method, and I am not wanting to use reflection to get hold of the Class and Method name.

For Error logging I can get the stack off the exception but how do I do this without an exception to get the StackTrace off?

Comment: Getting class and method information is basically what reflection is all about. Why do you want t avoid reflection in this case? It's like saying "I want to add two numbers without using the addition operator...".

Comment: Because, reflection is slow and expesive regarding performance, I was looking for a more efficent way.

Comment: That sounds like premature optimization to me. How fast is your current solution using reflection and what is your performance goal, i.e., how fast must the alternative solution be?

Comment: If you're writing this logging inside the methods have you considered using [nameof()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof)?

Comment: I will have to do some profiling to answer that. Currently people have been hard coding the names in which is far from optimal, or using reflection, I am just wondering if there is a more optimal solution.

Comment: Are you a Java programmer by chance? This is C#, reflection is fast enough to not notice it.

Comment: If it's just for diagnostics, there is [`CallerMemberName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute) and friends.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the information about the caller using [caller attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information)

```
public void Log(Exception ex, [CallerFilePath]string callerFilePath = null, [CallerMemberName]string callerMemberName = null, [CallerLineNumber]int callerLineNumber = 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Message: {ex.Message} # File: {callerFilePath} # Line: {callerLineNumber} # Member: {callerMemberName}"  );
}
```

When the method is called the information about the caller will be passes to you by the compiler, you don't need to manually specify the parameters.

Comment: Witchcraft and wizardry ☉_☉

Comment: @titan OMG DUDE!!!!!, that is amazing!!!

Answer (score 3):

Using reflection to get this data is rather expensive.

```
|               Method |          Mean |      Error |     StdDev |
|--------------------- |--------------:|-----------:|-----------:|
| MethodNameReflection | 1,452.4709 ns | 24.5287 ns | 50.6561 ns |
|     MethodNameNameOf |     0.0543 ns |  0.0521 ns |  0.0678 ns |
|             TypeName |    14.4099 ns |  0.3964 ns |  0.7543 ns |
|   TypeNameReflection | 1,659.5866 ns | 33.1575 ns | 90.7682 ns |
```

And the Code (Using BenchmarkDotNet)

```
public class CurrentMethodInfoBenchmarks
{
    [Benchmark]
    public string MethodNameReflection() => MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;

    [Benchmark]
    public string MethodNameNameOf() => nameof(MethodNameNameOf);

    [Benchmark]
    public string TypeName() => GetType().Name;

    [Benchmark]
    public string TypeNameReflection() => MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
}
```

Using CallerMemberAttributes should also be similarly fast as like `nameof()` it will be a compile time constant.

Comment: Expensive compared to *what*? If that logging takes an object and serializes it for example, those "large" numbers look tiny anyway...

Answer (score 1):

you can use [System.Environment.StackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) property